# How to Change ModX 1.0.4J-r1 Language from Japanese to English?

Tags: web, content-management-system, modx, web-development-server

I basically cannot understand all whats written in the interface because its all japanese. Google translate wont work.

I tried upgrading (doing the http://url.com/install) but it does not work. it just directing me to the website

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this directly in phpmyadmin. Go to the table `modx_system_settings` and change field `manager_language` to `english`.

Maybe you need to clear your cache.